# How can I find out what value my select box is selected to with Protractor version 1.0.0 rc?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a select box on my page like this:

```
<select id="typeSelect"
        ng-model="typeId"
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in types"></select>
```

When my page controller starts it should get a list of types from the server. Once the list is ready then it should select the first type which will have a value of "*".

I am very confused about how Protractor can interface with a select list for clicking on a selection and for determining what is selected.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I can test if the value is "*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here's one of my tests, adapted to your case:

```
describe('typeSelect startup', function() {
  var typeSelect;

  beforeEach(function() {
    /* 
     * I don't know how your list is getting updated with server data
     * But if it's the result of an action you have to perform it and
     * declare your elements into the .then() function
     */
    updateButton.click().then(function() {
      // might be necessary but not always
      browser.waitForAngular();
      typeSelect = element(by.id('typeSelect'));
    });
  });

  it('should have "*" value', function() {
    expect(typeSelect.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('*');
  });
});
```